# VMware Workstation 15 Pro on Ubuntu 18.04 with Linux Kernel 5

Tags: kernel, vmware

I recently upgraded my Ubuntu 18.04 to linux kernel 5.0.7.
All apps working fine except from VMware Workstation 15 Pro that requires GCC compiler ver. 8.3.0 (from current ver. 7.3.x).
I've tried to apply some how-tos but it seems that I cant't upgrade or install ver. 8.3.0 so I returned back to old kernel 4.15.x.
Can anyone has succeeded with the latest kernel or anything else?
(my current desktop environment is Cinnamon Desktop 4.0.9 if that matters).
I will appreciate your assistance.
Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Here is what I had to do.  I used Synaptic to install GCC8, and CPP 8.  Once that was done, I ran VMware Workstation 15, and it rebuild the modules, and it was OK.

If you don't have Synaptic installed, just press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> on your keyboard to open Terminal. When it opens, run the command(s) below:

```
sudo apt install synaptic
```

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your assistance. I installed gcc and cpp

$gcc --version
gcc (Ubuntu 8.2.0-1ubuntu2~18.04) 8.2.0

and kernel 5.0.7 but I still get an error message when I start vmware. It asks for version 8.3.0 and it doesn't run. Do you think the problem is with kernel 5.0.7. Should I try the older version 5.0? Once again thank you.

Comment: I would try an older version, just to be sure that it works, and its not something else.

Comment: Thank you for your assistance. I'll try that.